# Using NPN transistors as switches for low-current, 3VDC infrared transmitter device

Tags: arduino, switches, opto-isolator, solid-state-relay

I'm currently trying to hack up an IR remote for electric holiday candles so that I can use Amazon Alexa or Google Home to turn them on or off.  To do so, I need to trigger the switches on the hand-held IR remote that comes with the candles.

I attempted to do this using NPN transistors controlled by a micro-controller.

I connected the remote to the micro-controller's VCC and ground pins to provide it with power.  I then used two GPIO pins to supply voltage to a pair of NPN resistors (separately).  When I pushed either pin HIGH, it would allow current to flow across the transistor associated with that pin, acting as a closed switch (I hoped).

I then placed each transistor in the remote control's circuits in place of the mechanical switches.

The problem I have is that I can get the remote to treat whichever transistor is across the ON circuit to work, but the one for OFF fails.  It doesn't matter which transistor or which PIN is used.  ON works, OFF fails.

I have tested all both orientations of emitter versus collector in the OFF switch location, as well, in case current flow direction was an issue.  It has no impact.  ON works OFF fails still.

So why can I get the one to work and not the other?  I don't have a diagram of the actual IR remote circuit, I merely followed the traces to see how the switches are wired up.  I know I have that much right because I can use a physical switch of my own in place of them (or just a wire shunt) and they fire exactly as if the remote's own buttons had been pressed.

What's going on here?  Why can't I use NPN transistors for this job?

**UPDATE:** I measured the voltage across a few points for further insight.

```
ON PIN 1 to Ground = 3.3V
ON PIN 2 to Ground = 0V
ON PIN 2 to VCC = 3.3V
ON PIN 1 to ON PIN 2 = 3.06V
```

These make sense.  On pin #2 is basically ground.  The switch allows the current from pin one to make it to ground, completing some internal circuit that causes it to fire the IR.

```
OFF PIN 1 to Ground = 3.13V
OFF PIN 2 to Ground = 3.13V
OFF PIN 1 to OFF PIN 2 = 0.01V
OFF PIN 2 to OFF PIN 1 = -0.01V
```

Perhaps this will shed more light on the problem.  It seems that the voltage potential is so low between the OFF pins that it would not be usable, but I confirmed that touching pins 1 and 2 of the OFF circuit together turned off the candle and the measurement of 0.01V is consistent.

Comment: Fyi, there is a specialized [Arduino stack](https://arduino.stackexchange.com).  (They have a similar policy towards component recommendation questions, though.)

Comment: Yeah, I understand the policy.  The issue is that I don't know what to buy.  The "problem" I'm trying to solve is how to control a switched circuit that has to be isolated from my main circuit.  The answer is a relay of some sort.  That I know already.  But I don't know which relay to purchase.  I'll reword the question generically, but if the answer I get is "Use a solid state relay", I will have gained nothing...

Comment: Measure voltage from each contact of the 'OFF' button to Ground and Vcc, with the button pressed and released. What do you get?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Interestingly, OFF 1 and 2 both measure 3.13v to ground.  ON 1 measures 3.13v to ground, as well, but ON 2 appears to be a ground.  ON 2 is 0v to ground and 3.3v to the 3.3v power source. That explains why ON works, I suppose.

Comment: There appears absolutely no reason this question should be closed.... and certainly not for the 'hold' reason given.

Comment: You more or less answered your own question in posing it @MichaelOryl    The buttons on your IR remote are probably scanned and draw very very small currents. So using BJT transistors is unlikely to work. The quick and dirty way would be to use some small reed relays so you don't have to solve the current analysis problem. It sounds as if your ON switch is not scanned, so your BJT worked ....but the OFF button may be scanned so it didn't.

Comment: @JackCreasey Originally the question was asking which kind of small, DIP solid state relay I should be using to solve the switch issue.  But product recommendations are not allowed, so the question was put on hold.  So I edited it to list the "problem" I was having and you gave me the obvious solution; a relay.  Except I was hoping to use a cheap SSR chip relay to do it, and I can't figure which ones would work because I don't understand the nomenclature in the spec sheets and such.

Comment: @JackCreasey I am interested, however, in what you mean by "scanned" in your comment.  Thanks very much.

Comment: An SSR won't work since it cannot provide a low enough voltage across the contact points ....in addition the leakage current of an SSR may well be above the current flows through the switches. ....Typically a scanned keypad might look like this: http://www.eastn.eu/sites/www.eastn.eu/files/u15/matrix_0.gif   ...though many today may not have the diodes if they use current sensing. You can see from this that use of a voltage free contact (reed relay) could replace any key on the keypad.

Comment: You could just do away with the remote and emulate the IR instead. Plenty of arduino projects that do that.

Comment: @Passerby Yes, that's my backup plan for getting this to work, but more important (to me) was figuring out why I couldn't get this thing to work in general and what I could use to deal with the situation.  Thanks.

Comment: @JackCreasey Thanks, Jack.  I'll just go the more conventional relay route.  Appreciate your patience.